# In Perforce/P4V, how can I replace a file with a version older than the branch it's on?

Tags: perforce, p4v

I have a development branch that was created by P4V's "Branch Files." I'd like to replace the contents of a subdirectory with an earlier version, just temporarily, and only on my machine. The trouble is, the earlier versions I want are from before the branch was created. If I try to use "Get Revision..." for this earlier changelist, the file disappears (because the entire dev branch didn't exist then).

Finding, syncing and manually copying the entire subtree over from some other location is a bit of a pain. Is there an easier way?

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like 'p4 copy' is what you want; see [http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/cmdref/p4_copy.html#1040665](http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/cmdref/p4%5fcopy.html#1040665)

Try something like:

```
p4 copy //depot/main/sub/directory/...@old-date //depot/mybranch/sub/directory/...
```

where the left hand side specifies exactly the "subdirectory with an older version", and the right hand side specifies where the files are to go in your branch.

Don't forget to 'p4 revert' when you're done working with this particular set of code; you don't want to 'p4 submit' these changes.